# Can a non-holomorphic function have a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, singularity

As far as my studies have brought me, I've only see so far the definition of a "pole" for a complex valued function $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb C$ if we assume that the function is holomorphic in a neighbourhood around a singularity $z_0$.

Does it make sense to talk about poles without this condition, i.e. without requiring holomorphicity around $z_0$?

Comment: You can define whatever you want, but generally you want holomorphicity around singularities to apply things like the residue theorem.

Comment: You *could* generalize "$f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$". Something like "there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$ such that $0<\inf_{U\setminus\{z_0\}} |z^mf(z)|$ and $\sup_{U\setminus\{z_0\}} |z^mf(z)|<\infty$" might allow you to speak of a pole of a quite general family of (even very noncontinuous) functions. Whether such a definition (or the defined concept) is useful, is a different question.